# What kind of symmetric codes have a very large minimum distance?

Tags: coding-theory, gray-code, reed-muller-codes

I am in search of symmetric error-correcting codes that have a very large minimum distance. A codebook $\mathcal{C}$ is called symmetric if $\bf{1}\in\mathcal{C}$. Now, if $[n,k,d]_2$ is a symmetric code, then I want $d\approx n/2$. Can anybody tell me the approximate candidate for such type of code?

Comment: As Kodlu says in their (+1) answer, it really depends on what exactly you mean by $d\approx n/2$. Using additive characters and (Weil-)Carlitz-Uchiyama bound on character sums you can construct families of codes with $d=n/2- K\sqrt n$ where $K$ is a constant you can choose. The catch is that $k$ is still relatively small. Roughly $k\approx K \log_2n$. These codes are the duals of BCH-codes. So to say that $d\approx n/2$ we need $n$ to be relatively large, and the *rate*, $k/n$, of these codes is quite low (tends to zero when $n$ grows).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exactly what you mean by $d\approx n/2.$

If you absolutely want $d= n/2$ then the code cannot be that large in cardinality.

A first order Reed Muller code will have minimum distance $d=n/2,$ for $n=2^k.$ Its codewords can also be represented as rows of the $2^k\times2^k$ Sylvester Hadamard Matrix and its complement, i.e.,
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c} H \\ 
J\oplus H \end{array}
\right]
$$
where $J$ is the all $1$'s matrix. So the number of codewords is at most twice the length. By the Plotkin bound if $C$ is a binary code of length $n$ and minimum distance $d\geq n/2$ we have
$$
|C|\leq 2n.
$$
See Theorem 4 in [these notes.](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Evenkatg/teaching/codingtheory/notes/notes4.pdf)

Comment: The reed Muller code that you have described, is it also symmetric?